# Equivalence of two SVM-type convex programs

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ be points in $\mathbb R^d$ and let $p \in [1,\infty]$. For any positive $c$ and $t$, consider the problems

\begin{align}
&\min_{w \in \mathbb R^d} \|w\|^2_2 \text{ subject to }z_i^\top w \ge c\|w\|_p + 1\,\forall i \in [n],\tag{1}\\
&\min_{w \in \mathbb R^d} \|w\|_2 + t\|w\|_p \text{ subject to }z_i^\top w \ge 1\,\forall i \in [n].\tag{2}
\end{align}

I read a document https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02931.pdf (see Remark 3.1 therein), and the author says that for any value of $c$, there exists a value of $t$ such that problems (1) and (2) are equivalent.

**Question.** How is that ?

Comment: What does `equivalent' mean in this context?

Comment: My understanding is that the author means the sets of solutions (minimizers) are the same. I've added a reference to the author's claim.